# c++ string member function substr usage

Tags: c++, string, substring, substr

Please tell me if I am understanding the the substr member function correctly?
`result = result.substr(0, pos) + result.substr(pos + 1);`
It takes the string from pos, 0 until (but not including),  `remove[i]`
and then `+ result.substr(pos + 1);` concatenates the rest of the string, except but not including the string / char in `remove`?

```
string removeLetters2(string text, string remove)
{
    int pos;
    string result = text;

    for (int i = 0; i < remove.length(); i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            pos = result.find(remove[i]);                
            if (pos == string::npos)                      
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                result = result.substr(0, pos) +
                result.substr(pos + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891610/c-how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you are asking if

```
result = result.substr(0, pos) +
         result.substr(pos + 1);
```

removes the character at position `pos`, right?

### *Short Answer:*

Yes.

### *Longer Answer:*

The two-argument call takes the start **index** and the **length** (the one argument call goes to the end of string).

It helps to imagine the string like this:

```
F o o / B a r
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   <- indices
```

Now remove `/`:

```
F o o / B a r
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   <- indices
1 2 3 |         <- 1st length
      | 1 2 3   <- 2nd length

result = result.substr(0, 3)   <- from index 0 with length 3
       + result.substr(4);     <- from index 4 to end
```

As a programmer, always be aware of the difference between distance/index and length.

### *Better: If index is known:*

Your code creates two new, temporary strings, which are then concatenated into a third temporary string, which is then copied to `result`.

It would be better to ask `string` to erase (wink wink) in place:

```
result.erase(pos,1);
// or by iterator
string::iterator it = ....;
result.erase(it,it+1);
```

This leaves more optimization freedom to the `string` implementer, who may choose to just move all characters after pos by one to the left. This could, in a specialized scenario, be implemented with a single assignment, a single loop, and within the loop with the x86 swap instruction.

### *Better: If characters to be deleted are known:*

Or, but I am not sure if this gives better performance, but it *may* give better *code*, the algorithm `remove_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>

// this would remove all slashes, question marks and dots
....
    std::string foobar = "ab/d?...";
    std::remove_if (foobar.begin(), foobar.end(), [](char c) {
        return c=='/' || c=='?' || '.';
    });
```

`remove_if` accepts any function object.

If there is just one character, it gets easier:

```
// this would remove all slashes
std::remove (foobar.begin(), foobar.end(), '/');
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the answer to your question is "yes", there is a better way to go about what you are trying to do. Use [`string::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/), like this:

```
result.erase(pos, 1);
```

This API is designed for removal of characters from the string; it achieves the same result much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this function removes all letters in `remove` from `text`.

Answer (score 0):

since you seem to delete more than one type of character have a look at `remove_if` from `<algorithm>` with a special predicate too, although the response of dasblinkenlignt is the good one