# Is there a removeAt function for strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to C++. I know there is an [`std::remove`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891610/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string) method to remove characters from a string, but is there a `remove_at` method of some kind that will allow me to remove the characters at a certain index in the string? For example,

```
string s = "aBcDeF";
s = s.remove_at(4).remove_at(2);
```

would result in

```
"aBDF"
```

Is there a function in the standard library to do this?

Comment: std::basic_string<T>::erase

Comment: I guess reading the documentation was too hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method is called `erase`. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "aBcDeF";
    s.erase( 4, 1 ).erase( 2, 1 );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
aBDF
```

Take into account the order in which the method is called. Of course you could split this one call in two separates calls.

For example

```
s.erase( 2, 1 );
s.erase( 3, 1 );
```

If you neded to create a new string you can simply initialize a new string with this one. For example

```
std::string t = s;
t.erase( 2, 1 );
t.erase( 3, 1 );
```

Comment: I think this is great, but it deletes characters from the original string instead of returning a new one. Sorry for being ambiguous about immutability; I will update my question to reflect.

Comment: What about creating this new modified string yourself? nothing difficult there

Comment: @JamesKo `string s2 = s;`, and the modifiying s2?

Answer (score 3):

`std::string::remove` has an overload which gets the position of the character to remove and the amount of characters to remove from that position. so your code is basically

```
s.remove(4,1).remove(2,1);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/

The first overload will do what you want. std::string has quite a few useful methods, and I'm sure not too many people can remember them all. A handy reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/