# Delete certain characters from wstring

Tags: c++, wstring

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891610/how-to-remove-characters-from-a-string), except that I'm dealing with `wstring` rather than `string`. I switched the types to `wstring` and `wchar_t` and compiled it but I'm getting an error. This is the code:

```
int delete_punc(std::wstring& str)
{
    wchar_t* chars = L".,!?";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(chars); i++)
        str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), chars[i]), str.end());

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<wchar_t>::iterator
{aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<wchar_t*, std::basic_string<wchar_t> >}’
to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)
```

**Edit:**
I also tried other brute force variants. Both returned the same error.

```
int delete_punc(std::wstring& str)
{
    //str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), L"."), str.end());
    //str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), "."), str.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also be interested in the warnings you get with `-Wall`. Why did you bring in a pointer? Couldn't it be `std::wstring`, too?

Comment: Plus, that does not look like the real code. The error doesn't fit here.

Comment: @LogicStuff The error points to the line with ``str.erase``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to `#include <algorithm>`, so the compiler could find only [this overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove).

More substantial errors in your code - you are using a pointer when you don't need to, which leads to the common `sizeof(pointer)` mistake, signed/unsigned comparison warning.

You are also calling `std::string::erase` in a loop, which might trigger more reallocations and character copying than you'd get with `std::erase` and `std::remove_if` with a lambda and `std::any_of` with a `std::wstring`. Try that instead.

Comment: It finally worked after including ``algorithm`` and changing the code to this form: ``str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), L'.'), str.end());``. Thank you